# See YouTube dislikes

Tags: json, google-chrome, youtube

YouTube has removed the dislike numbers. I was able to find the dislike number on Chrome (let's see for how long).

### How to do it

Load the page and wait until all sources have been downloaded. Then go to *Network* and search for *dislike*. You may find a JSON with the key `simpleText`. This is how it looks like:

[image]

**Note:** This file is getting cached. So ensure that you watch a video that you never saw before.

### The Problem

Instead of searching for that string over and over again, I would like to have a command to enter it in the console.

**This is the correct path:**

```json
onResponseReceivedEndpoints[1].reloadContinuationItemsCommand.continuationItems[0].commentThreadRenderer.comment.commentRenderer.actionButtons.commentActionButtonsRenderer.dislikeButton.toggleButtonRenderer.defaultServiceEndpoint.performCommentActionEndpoint.clientActions[0].updateCommentVoteAction.voteCount.simpleText
```

In console you can type `ytInitialData`. That object includes `onResponseReceivedEndpoints[0]` but not `onResponseReceivedEndpoints[1]`. The problem is, `onResponseReceivedEndpoints[0]` doesn't include `reloadContinuationItemsCommand`.

### The attempted way to solve it

Tab *Preview* -> right click the wanted object -> click on *Store string as global variable*

[image]

Now when you go to console and type `temp1` (`1` if it's your first global variable), you will get the result. But that works only for the current tab. When I open another tab for a YouTube video, I get the error:

> temp1 is not defined

So how can I get the value of that object with a simple command?

Comment: Haven't tried, but, it might be worth it= can you use localStorage instead of temp1?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes you can do this manually, but the object will be _undefined_ then.